# CodeIgniter + Grocery Crud - how to set fields to either on/off (bool, checkbox) and also how to set it to be a select dropdown of numbers (1-10)

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

CodeIgniter + Grocery Crud - how to set fields to either on/off (bool, checkbox) and also how to set it to be a select dropdown of numbers (1-10) ?

I have grocerycrud set up, and on some fields they are either:

bool values (but set as ints or varchars so groceycrud shows it as a

or

select dropdown with values 0-10 (these are stored as ints, but it is for a rating system)

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can check  [field_type](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type) method. In your case you need:

field type true_false for on/off boolean. For example:

```
$crud->field_type('my_field','true_false');
```

The default on/off for grocery CRUD is active/inactive (1/0) but you can change the text from the lang file at:  assets/grocery_crud/languages/english.php (or your language) to on off.

For the second scenario of dropdown list you can use the field_type with type "dropdown" or "enum". For more you can go to: http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type#dropdown-field  and  http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type#enum-field that also have examples.

Also consider that the dropdown type is available only for versions >= 1.3.2

Comment: It seems to not work in view mode; I defined something like this $this->grocery_crud->field_type('main', 'true_false', array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No')); that works properly for Add and Edit, but in view mode it is shown the possible values 0 and 1. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values of radio buttons in the config file for your language. for english, it's here:

assets\grocery_crud\languages\english.php

Just change these 2 lines:

```
$lang['form_inactive']            = 'inactive';
$lang['form_active']            = 'active';
```

To whatever you want, in your case, something like:

```
$lang['form_inactive']            = 'female';
$lang['form_active']            = 'male';
```

and make sure to change the field to boolean, if you haven't yet:

$this->grocery_crud->change_field_type('field_name','true_false');

Answer (score 0):

```
// now This part is for update or edit
$crud->callback_edit_field('government',array($this,'radio_edit_callback'));

//Function for the callback_edit_field 
public function radio_edit_callback($value) {
    //$value will be having the present value(Y or N) that is in the list or database.
    if($value == 'Y') {
        return '<input type="radio" name="government" value=" '.$value.' " checked="checked" /> Yes &nbsp;
       <input type="radio"  name="government" value="N" /> No ';
    } else {
        return '<input type="radio" name="government" value="Y" /> Yes &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="government" value=" '.$value.' " checked="checked" /> No';
    }
}
```